# Codemagic `Fetch signing files` script exited with status code 9

Tags: continuous-integration, codemagic

Hello i'm new at flutter and don't have a mac, i'm use Codemagic, i have the keys been set at the codemagic.yaml but get the error:

Log:

```
Executing AppStoreConnect action fetch-signing-files failed unexpectedly. Detailed logs are available at "/var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn/T/codemagic-23-11-21.log". To see more details about the error, add `--verbose` command line option.
Executing AppStoreConnect action fetch-signing-files failed unexpectedly. Detailed logs are available at "/var/folders/m7/h1mg7c7x40ddjz6mxjxm3htr0000gn/T/codemagic-23-11-21.log". To see more details about the error, add `--verbose` command line option.


Build failed :|
Step 3 script `Fetch signing files` exited with status code 9


Build failed :|
Step 3 script `Fetch signing files` exited with status code 9
```

Script part of the codemagic.yaml:

```
- name: Fetch signing files
    script: |
                app-store-connect fetch-signing-files $BUNDLE_ID --type IOS_APP_STORE --create
```

Am i forget anything?

Comment: hey it's a quite hard to say what exactly wrong with your configuration since "status code 9" is a generic response from App Store Connect. My best guess would you missed or provided incorrect credentials. Read more about iOS code signing here https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-code-signing/signing-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this PR](https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/cli-tools/pull/168) introduces better error handling for such kind of errors. The PR was merged early today and you can run a new build to see detailed error message.

And from the changes it seems you provided a wrong value for private key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i have provided wrong private key, but now i have another problem, while build it returns the error: 
Completed configuring code signing settings
Did not find matching provisioning profiles for code signing!
Generated options for exporting the project....
No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer accoun...

I am sure the keys are correct :/

Comment: nice to hear the original question was addressed  feel free to accept the answer - it can help other users to fix the same issue. If you have further questions probably it will be better to create a new post or ask them in slack.codemagic.io